# How do you change the axis labels in a list of ggplots?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm creating a list of ggplots in order to make an animation.  I want to highlight a label on the x-axis, and the position of this highlight changes over the different frames of animation.

Here's a sample plot.  The first axis label should be highlighted in frame one, and the second in frame two.

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) + 
  geom_boxplot() 
p_list <- list()

for(i in 1:2)  
{
  x_label_cols <- rep("grey50", 3)
  x_label_cols[i] <- "red"
  p_list[[i]] <- p + 
    opts(
      axis.text.x = theme_text(
        colour = x_label_cols
      )
    )
}
```

Unfortunately, it seems that `x_label_cols` is evaluated when the plot is printed, not when it is created, so both frames have the second label highlighted.  Thus  `print(p_list[[1]])` displays incorrectly.

How do I get different axis label colours for each plot in the list?

Comment: In case you are interested, creating the animation is as easy as `saveGIF(print(p_list))`. (`animation` package required.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not adjust the opts within `saveGIF()`? As far as I know, `opts()` works just like `options()`, but then specifically for ggplot2. So in your code you set the options twice, but only print the graphs after the last change of the options. Hence, you have to include the options change in the code run within `saveGIF()`.

This code does it for me :

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) +
  geom_boxplot()

saveGIF(
  sapply(1:2,function(x){
      x_label_cols <- rep("grey50", 3)
      x_label_cols[x] <- "red"
      print(p + 
        opts(axis.text.x = theme_text(colour = x_label_cols))
      )
  })
)
```

Gives :

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Minor downside is that it mixes the the plot creation code with the printing code, but I suppose that I can move that function elsewhere to pretty up the code.  And it definitely works, so good thinking!

Comment: @Richie : actually, you only need to create the plot once. It's only the options you change, not the plot. So technically, you don't create the plot within saveGIF, you create the correct options. ;)